# Limitting the number of numbers using substrings cpp

Tags: c++

I'm having trouble limiting the number of letters I wasn't appearing. I'm trying to get just the last two but that has been a difficulty. This is what I did;

```cpp
if (year.length() > 2) {
year = year.substr(0, 2);
}
```

For example, if you have the year 2016, just 16 is selected.

Comment: What was the result of what you did? You gave us the expected result (`"16"`) for a given input (`"2016"`), but not the actual result.

Comment: Imagine it's an input rather than result of a calculation @JaMiT

Comment: @janitorjames Huh? I already said that `"2016"` is an input, so you mean I should imagine that your desired result (the `"16"`) is also an input rather than the result of your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`subString` first parameter is the starting position and second is the number of strings from that position, so first, we take out the length of the string subtract -2 from it.
the second parameter is 2 because we need two characters.

eg : 2016 , first parameter is year subString(4-2,2);

```
year.substr(year.length() - 2,2)
```